# How did Norwegian "huske" derive from ON "hugsa"?

Tags: old-norse, diachronic, norwegian

In Norse and Norwegian both, `hug` means "memory". Norse `hugsa` and Nynorsk `hugse` is "to remember".

Is there a reason that `s` was attached? I can't think of any other verbs derived from nouns in this way. How did `hugsa` evolve to `huske`, which is how it's written in Bokmål? Presumably that's some kind of metathesis, but I haven't seen that anywhere either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of the letter s forms an iterative verb. There are more examples in Germanic languages, e.g. Low German *hoppen* "to hop", High German *hopsen* "to bounce, to lollop".

The second step is called metathesis and this is again not an unusual process, for instance the English word *wasp* is derived from *to weave* (because of the nests that wasps build) with and s-suffix and metathesis.

Comment: The connection between the IE words for "wasp" and "weave" is not universally accepted, especially since wasps (unlike spiders) do not actually weave anything (see de Vann, s.v. vespa). But of course metathesis is a well-attested phenomenon.

Comment: Norwegian data would be more convincing.